# Photo taken from iphone gets rotated 90 degrees on Android phone

Tags: android

Scenario : 
The photo rotated 90 degrees when the picture was taken from the iPhone camera and uploaded on the server and trying to load the same photo on android device.

What I found so far is Meta information(EXIF data) is ignored by the Android system before downloading the image. When photo uploaded from iPhone, the EXIF information of that particular photo is something like this: orientation 6 Rotated 90 CCW, but when it comes to android this value becomes: orientation 0(UNDEFINED)

I tried a couple of approaches but did not work, let me know if anyone faced similar issue or any solution or work around for this, Thanks in advance.

Sample snippet code :

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
            resultBitmap = decodeStream(inputStream, null, bmOptions);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(inputStream);
            String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
            int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) : ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
            int rotationAngle = 0;
            if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) rotationAngle = 90;
            else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) rotationAngle = 180;
            else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) rotationAngle = 270;
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle);
            Bitmap rotated =  Bitmap.createBitmap(resultBitmap,0,0,resultBitmap.getWidth(),resultBitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
            if(rotated != null){
                resultBitmap = rotated;
            }
enter code here
```